revalidate nextjs dynamic metadata title
Helllo,
I have this metadata code on my page.tsx, but revalidate don't work
I need something similar a update title in interval 30 seconds
import { cookies } from 'next/headers';
import ChatStart from '@/components/chat/chatStart/chatStart';
import { Metadata } from 'next';
import { URL } from '../../../config';

export async function generateMetadata(): Promise<Metadata> {
  const cookieStore = cookies();

  const token_user = cookieStore.get('token_user')?.value || '';

  const questions = await fetch(`${URL}/count`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${token_user}`,
    },
    next: { revalidate: 30 },
  }).then((res) => res.json());

  const count = questions.totalCount;

  return {
    title: `(${count}) - Questions `,
  };
}

export default function Home() {

  return (
      <>
      <ChatStart  />
    </>
  );
}

In another code snippet, i using client-side but revalidate don't work too
Additional information
version next 14.1.3
I tested on PREVIEW vercel and localhost
I tested on server side and client side
